# How to pass variable between html tag, javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, variables, input

I have several divs, which are made automatically by php script. Each div have and record from mysql database in it. And hidden input with value of unique ID. What I wan't to do is when I click on each of this divs, I would like to open overlay with div in middle and use this id to acces another data in database. I have working overlay. I just don't know how to pass that variable.

It's something like this:

```
echo "<div class='friend'>".$a["username"]."<input type='hidden' value='$id'/>"."</div>";
```

I hope someone will understand what I'm asking for. :) I know it's terrible explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clean code should be this:

```
echo '<div class="friend"> ' . $a["username"] . '<input type="hidden" value="' . $id . '"/></div>';
```

But way more cleaner would be having a list of your friends like this:

```
echo '<ul>';
echo '<li><a href="#' . $id . '" class="friend">' . $a["username"] . '</a></li>';
echo '</ul>';
```

When using jQuery for example you can handle click events with a few lines and pass your user id to an external PHP like this:

```
$('.friend').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.get('/userDetails.php?uid=' + $(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
    alert(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is great I just have one problem I can't trigger overlay with it. It does not work at all. Any idea why, I put any div id or class as a trigger and it works, perfect. But than i put .friend and nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$('div.friend').click(function(){
   val = $(this).find("input").val();

   //open your overlay with the value as a parameter
});
```

Comment: And what this will do? I need to get that id and put it to php variable? Anyway thank you for quick answer.

Comment: You will then need to use ajax to call your php script and pass the val variable as GET or POST variable. I assumed you were already doing this because you said that you already had the overlay working.

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
       echo "<div class='friend' onclick='(function(id){ $(\'#overlay\').html(id).show(); }(\'$id\'));'>".$a["username"]."<input type='hidden' value='$id'/>"."</div>";
```